# how do I insert a long sequence of "return" variables in many diff locations?

Tags: python, function, variables, return

I have a function called preset_parser in mylibrary.py that takes argument filename, i.e. preset_parser(filename), and returns a long list of variables, e.g.

```
def preset_parser(filename):

... defines variable values based on reading the file

   return presetsdf, preset_name, preset_description, preset_instructions, preset_additional_notes, preset_placeholder, pre_user_input, post_user_input, prompt, engine, finetune_model, temperature, max_tokens, top_p, fp, pp, stop_sequence, echo_on, preset_pagetype, preset_db, user, organization
```

So then I call this function from many other programs, where I do this:

```
from mylibrary import presets_parser

presetsdf, preset_name, preset_description, preset_instructions, preset_additional_notes, preset_placeholder, pre_user_input, post_user_input, prompt, engine, finetune_model, temperature, max_tokens, top_p, fp, pp, stop_sequence, echo_on, preset_pagetype, preset_db, user, organization = presets_parser(filename)
```

This is redundant and fragile (it breaks if the list of variables changes).  What is the better way to do it? I know it must be simple.

Comment: Store all the variables in a container of some kind and return it. Good candidates would be a dictionary, `namedtuple`, or a dataclass. A more powerful way would be to define a custom `class`.

Answer (score 2):

The "general" solution to your problem is to make a class.

```
class ParseResult:
  def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c
    self.d = d
```

There are several ways in Python to automate this pattern. If your return values have some natural sort of "sequencing", you might use [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or its typed cousin [`NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple).

```
ParseResult = namedtuple("ParseResult", 'a b c d')
```

or

```
class ParseResult(NamedTuple):
  a: TypeOfA
  b: TypeOfB
  c: TypeOfC
  d: TypeOfD
```

This creates a richer "tuple-like" construct with named arguments.

If your return values don't make sense as a tuple and don't have any sort of natural notion of sequence, you can use the more general-purpose [`dataclass` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class ParseResult:
  a: TypeOfA
  b: TypeOfB
  c: TypeOfC
  d: TypeOfD
```

Then, in any case, return a value of this new type which has rich names (and possibly types) for its values.

Answer (score 0):

You could return a dictionary instead:

```
def myfunction():
    ...
    mydict = {
        'variable1': value1,
        'variable2': value2,
        'anothervariable': anothervalue,
        'somevariable': somevalue,
    }
    return mydict
```

Answer (score 0):

I could think of a couple better ways, but I'm not sure what your limitations are? You could create a class then return the instance you would need to initiate in the parser function:

```
class Preset:
    __init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.sdf
        self.name
        self.description
        self.etc...
```

then in your function:

```
preset = Preset
preset.sdf = file_data[0] //however you've parsed you data?
preset.name = file_data[1]
```

or you could make it a dictionary:

```
preset {
    sdf: file_data[0]
    name: file_data[1]
}
```

not sure if you have some limitation on what is returned from your function?